How to properly manage redirection in React using React Router and React Query
The React SPA I am working on is using React Query, Ory (as auth provider) and React Router. A typical pattern I need to implement is the following:

User not logged in and goes to /login -> no redirect
User not logged in and goes to /signup -> no redirect
User logged in and goes to /login -> redirect to /home
User logged in and goes to /signup -> redirect to /home
User logged in, is in step X of onboarding and goes to any page -> redirect to step X
User logged in, is fully onboarded and goes to /login or /signup -> redirect to /home
User logged in, is fully onboarded and goes to any page not (/login or /signup) -> redirect to targeted page

There are several ways to check if a user is logged in:

Proactively, using for instance Ory's "whoami" API (concretely, it makes a call to their server and responds with 200 if the cookie is a valid authentication proof and 401 otherwise).
Reactively, if any API call to my backend responds with 401.

I have implemented in the React Query cache the following logic:
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    queryCache: new QueryCache({
      onError: (error) => {
        if (error?.statusCode === 401) {
          if (
            error?.url != "ory-session" &&
            error?.url != "login" &&
            error?.url != "logout"
          ) {
            /* Cannot use React Router because QueryClientProvider is above BrowserRouter in the component tree */
            if (!window.location.pathname.includes("/login")) {
              window.history.pushState({}, "", "/login");
              window.location.reload();
            }
          }
        }
      },
    }),

On the other hand, I have tried the following:

Create a custom hook that manages the onboarding step + redirection if already logged in
Create a component "RedirectWhenLoggedIn" on top of /login and /signup
Create a component "RedirectOnboarding" on top of any other page

However, this creates messy redirections and race conditions with React Query (especially when "logging out" or when checking the current onboarding step of the user - which is based on server state).
This is a quite typical pattern request: what is the best practice for implementing it?

Do you have a client-side "source of truth" for authenticated users that the frontend UI can check, or does everything need to do an explicit check via "whoami"? Your post appears to be about more than just checking authenticated/unauthenticated users and redirecting them accordingly. Can you [edit] to narrow the focus of your post/question to a single specific issue and include a [mcve] of the relevant code related to it?

Generally in SPA  We have AuthProvider which manage all auth related stuff like getting JWT token and managing status of the session. this details is shared by using context called AuthContext and accessed using hook, like useAuth().
We divide the routes in two categories
1.public routes: which don't require user to be logged in and can not be accessed  if user is logged in.
2.Private routes: which require user to be logged in and can't be accessed if user is not logged in
RoutesProvider uses a login status shared by AuthProvider to render betweeen both public routes and private routes
Here is very basic implementation
    PublicRoutes=()=>{

      return <>
      {/***your code using react router for login and signup pages***/}
      </>

    }

    PrivateRoute=()=>{

      return <>
      {/***your code using react router use defautl route to goto home page***/}
      </>

    }


    RoutesProvider=()=>{
      
      const [isLoggedIn]=useAuth();//i assume we have authprovider which manage all session related activity


      return <>
          {/*User not logged in and goes to /login -> no redirect*/)
          {!isLoggedIn? <PublicRoutes/>:<PrivateRoutes/> }
      </>
          }

I hope this will be helpfull :)
